# android.test.purchased: sending purchase request

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play

In- App Purchase implementation

I want to the return a product list available in market place and  price list of each product .

Is there any option to get the product list and price from in app purchase market server . I have added 5 product and I want to get list of these products in my apps ...

Android market server return the amount for in app purchase product

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge, We are only purchase one by one. Can not receive a list ID or send them to Market.